# How to get my public IP from XMPP bind message?

Tags: android, xmpp, ip, public, smack

I'm writing Android app and need to know my public IP. In my app i'm using [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/) library for conversation with XMPP server (that needed not only to know my IP)

Bind message, received from server looks like:

```
<iq id="_xmpp_bind1" type="result">
   <bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind">
      <jid>user@jabber.example.com/Smack</jid>
   </bind>
</iq>
```

But I'm waiting it looks like:

```
<iq id="_xmpp_bind1" type="result">
    <bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind">
       <jid>user@jabber.example.com/11.22.33.44:12345</jid
    </bind>
</iq>
```

Where instead of 11.22.33.44 should be my public IP.

Comment: So based on your answer below, your question was actually "How do I get the server to assign me a JID resource during bind"?  And you omitted to mention that you have a custom server which allocates the user's IP address as resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of problem. My Smack library itself provokes server to send such bind response.

It sends such bind request:

```
<iq id="Um486-7" type="set">
   <bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind">
      <resource>Smack</resource>
   </bind>
</iq>
```

So resource is specified explicitly by Smack's bind request. 
That situation is arises when using method:

```
public void login (String username, String password)
```

To avoid such behavior next method should be used:

```
public void login (String username, String password, String resource)
```

and `resource` should be set to `null`

Comment: You could also configure your server to ignore the requested bind parameter coming from the client and always send the custom IP-related resource.

Answer (score 1):

What XMPP server are you using?

It's likely you'd want to solve this a different way than you're proposing.  Your approach would leak your real IP address to everyone on your roster.  For example, an HTTP request to `http://ifconfig.me/` will return your external IP address without any extra hassle.

Comment: I connect to my own server, and roster is not containing from real people. It has only one buddy and it is a bot :) So leaking of IP address is not a bad thing.

Comment: In terms of using side service like http://ifconfig.me/ - that's a reasonable decision, but not the best. In that case my app becomes dependent of side service. And it generates additional traffic (returned page is not very heavy, but has a lot of useless data)