# How to get IP address of chat message sender using XMPP protocol in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, ip, xmpp, chat

I am developing an app which can respond to user's chat message. I need to know the IP address of the chat message sender. I am doing my app on Google app Engine and using XMPP protocol for chatting purposes. How to detect IP address of a chat message sender using XMPP protocol?

Comment: If you control the client/app and trust is not an issue, make it detect its own IP and send it as part of the message.

Answer (score 2):

Only the XMPP server knows the IP address. If you control the XMPP server you can write an extension to include the IP address in the messages somehow (or check if one is already available).

Comment: you could technically do this, but please don't unless you own all of the machines, networks, and users involved.  People get very upset about their IP address leaking, and it won't even work the way you expect if there is a NAT between the client and the server.

Answer (score 0):

[How to get my public IP from XMPP bind message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461722/how-to-get-my-public-ip-from-xmpp-bind-message)

http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0279.html

---

First the client sends an IQ-get request to its server.

**Example 1.** Client requests its IP address from the server

```
<iq from='romeo@montague.lit/orchard'
    id='ik2s7159'
    type='get'>
  <address xmlns='urn:xmpp:sic:1'/>
</iq>
```

The server then returns an IQ-result containing an  element containing an  element specifying the client's external IP address and, optionally, a  element specifying the client's external port.

**Example 2.** Server returns IP address and port

```
<iq id='ik2s7159'
    to='romeo@montague.lit/orchard'
    type='result'>
  <address xmlns='urn:xmpp:sic:1'>
    <ip>192.168.4.1</ip>
    <port>12345</port>
</iq>
```

Note that the IP address could be IPv4 or IPv6.

**Example 3.** Server returns IPv6 address

```
<iq id='ik2s7159'
    to='romeo@montague.lit/orchard'
    type='result'>
  <address xmlns='urn:xmpp:sic:1'>
    <ip>2001:db8::9:1</ip>
    <port>12345</port>
  </address>
</iq>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please summarise the link in your answer; that way, if the link goes stale the answer won't be completely useless.